# How to send cookies to client from node/express server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, cookies

I am having the hardest time sending cookies from my nodejs server to my browser. Below is my index.js (server side) code:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(
  cors({
       origin: "http://localhost:3000", 
       methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
       credentials: true
 })
);
let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 5000;
}

mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI).then(console.log("MongoDB Connection Success")).catch(err => console.log("MongoDB Connection Failed" + err))


app.use(session({
  secret: 'random secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  // store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.ATLAS_URI }),
  cookie: {
    expires: 7 * 24 * 6 * 60 * 1000,
    secure: false,
  },
}));
app.use(cookieParser())


app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use("/auth", auth)
```

I know a cookie is being created when i authenticate a user because if i uncomment out the `store` in `app.use(session({...})` i see session IDs and cookies in my mongodb. But how can I send it to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

try this config for the session options.
my version of express-session is "^1.17.2"

```
app.use(session({
   name: 'random name',
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   secret: 'random secret',
   store: MongoStore.create({
       mongoUrl: config.DatabaseUrl,
       ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 // = 14 days. Default
    })
}));
```

if this config does not work, check your passport authenticate function that set session true like the below example :

```
passport.authenticate('local.register', {session: true}, (err, user): void => {
   // When res has an Error
   if (err) return res.redirect('/auth/register');
   return res.redirect('/');
})(req, res);
```